# How to create a bootstrap 3.0 tab that fixed on left side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create a bootstrap 3.0 tab that **fixed on left side**, but the right side contents are Scrolled in body.

If any tabs are clicked, Contents automatically scrolled and move to its section.

Comment: can u show an example or your code here so we can figure out what u exactly want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because on Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working copy:
https://codepen.io/nabanitadasgupta/pen/KyapqE

I have created the same for you.Here is a complete working copy which has left bar as  fixed and once you click to a link it will scroll down to the specific div.

To scroll down to a specific `section` you have to set the `id` of a particular `div` where you want to scroll down and same `id` needs to be used in `href` tag to the link you want to click to.Example:

```
<a href="#tab1">Link2</a>
```

Now the `tab1` need to be set as a id in your body `div` or `paragraph`. Example:

```
  <p id="tab1">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum scelerisque tincidunt metus. Pellentesque lacus nulla, molestie nec augue ut, mollis vehicula eros.</p>
```

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Do not answer questions that ask you to write code or markup for them. That is not what Stack Overflow is for. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob I completely understand your concern and you are absolutely saying the correct thing. But Why I have answered here, the reason is, I think he is a beginner and doesn't have much idea about the same, and maybe with the basic structure which I have provided him, I can help him to start his work.I hope this will help him to an extent.

Comment: He being a beginner in no way gives you license to break Stack Overflow policy and rules.

Comment: @Sahin I think, my example will help you to start your work and I explained enough so that you can carry forward from here. Good luck!

Comment: @Rob ok so what you suggest me? Shall I delete my answer so that no way it can help someone or anyone?

Comment: Yes. Delete your answer. It is the proper thing to do. The question is near being closed now.

Comment: I just noticed. You, too, have not posted the markup to answer the question in your answer. Instead you have used a jsfiddle and put your own question into the off topic category. I have submitted your answer for removal also.

Comment: @Rob  if you are interested to delete someone answer than go ahead and do it. Thanks !!

Comment: @Rob remember one thing, everybody dont know all things. u dont like leave here. otherwise help people to learn. i am not a beginner to this. Everyday many beginner come to learn here. support them